# jquery display:block not working correclty when more than 2 divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 simple buttons, 3 simple divs. I need those divs to switch between each other based on button click.
this works fine.

problem: after first page load last div (sample text 3) is visible instead of first one (sample text 1).
only the first div is set to display:block. the rest is set to display:none.

javascipt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content-switch').hide().eq($('.buttons a.active').index()).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('.buttons a').click(function() {
        $(".content-switch").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn("slow")
        .siblings('.content-switch').fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<body>
 <div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" id="button1">Button 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="button2">Button 2</a>
  <a href="#" id="button2">Button 3</a>
 </div>

 <div class="buts" id="buts">
  <div style="display: block;position:absolute" class="content-switch" id="but1">
   <p>sample text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;position:absolute" class="content-switch" id="but2">
   <p>sample text 2</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;position:absolute" class="content-switch" id="but2">
   <p>sample text 3</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need to use both `$(window).load()` and `$(document).ready()` - it's just one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
.eq($('.buttons a.active').index())
```

to:

```
.eq(0)
```

So you have:

```
$('.content-switch').hide().eq(0).fadeIn("slow");
$('.buttons a').click(function () {
    $(".content-switch").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn("slow")
        .siblings('.content-switch').fadeOut("fast");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Thbzr/)**

`$('.buttons a.active').index()` returns `-1` because there is no `.buttons a.active` element which is why the third div shows.

An alternate solution is to put an active class on the first anchor and use your original code:

```
<a href="#" id="button1" class="active">Button 1</a>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NdMRT/)**